# Which prophets were killed?

Tags: quran, prophets, surat-al-imran

From [3:112](https://quran.com/3/112)

> "... they (People of the Book) have persistently disbelieved in God's revelation and killed prophets without any right" .

What prophets does this passage refer to? Are there any specific prophets to which this relates passage relates? I have not yet read the Bible but the only named prophet I can think of that was killed by the People of the Book (in his case the Sanhedrin) was Yehoshua.

Comment: There is no verse in the Qur'an or an authentic hadith that lists the names of those prophets.

Comment: If by Yehoshua you mean Jesus, then according to Islam the Israelites attempted to kill him but did not succeed (though the charge still falls on them since they tried). Other examples which come to mind, from the Bible and tradition include Isaiah, [Zechariah](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Chronicles%2024:21v), John the Baptist and some unnamed Prophets.

Comment: @Uma John the Baptist was killed by Herod

Comment: @Charlie The people are responsible when their king does something and they don't oppose it, but are satisfied with it. See [Matthew 17:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+17%3A12-13&version=NIV), and [Gill's](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/gill/matthew/17.htm) and  [Ellicot's](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/matthew/17.htm) commentary. You'd find similar in Islamic exegesis.

Comment: No one truly knows exactly how many prophets were killed. Because there are a total of 124,000 Prophets according to Islam but only 25 are mentioned in Quran and that too not in detail. Allah knows the Best.

Answer (score 5):

This refers to the Prophets that the Israelites killed. The charge is repeated in for example:

> #### ذلك بأنهم كانوا يكفرون بآيات الله ويقتلون النبيين بغير الحق
>
> That was because they disbelieved in the signs of Allah and killed the prophets without right.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:61](https://quran.com/2/61)</sup>
>
> #### فريقا كذبوا وفريقا يقتلون
>
> a party they denied, and another party they killed
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:70](https://quran.com/5/70)</sup>

The fact that the Israelites killed some of their Prophets is attested to

In the Tanakh itself:

> And he [Elijah] said: "I have been zealous for the Lord, the God of Hosts, for the children of Israel have forsaken Your covenant. They have torn down Your altars and **they have killed Your prophets** by the sword, and I have remained alone, and they seek my life to take it.
>
> <sup>— [1 Kings 19:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15903/jewish/Chapter-19.htm#v=10)</sup>
>
> And they disobeyed and rebelled against You, and they cast Your Law behind their backs, and **they slew Your prophets** who warned them, to bring them back to You, and they committed great provocations.
>
> <sup>— [Nehemiah 9:26](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16516/jewish/Chapter-9.htm#v=26)</sup>

And the Gospel:

> So you testify against yourselves that you are the descendants of those who **murdered the prophets**.
>
> <sup>— [Matthew 23:31](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+23:31)</sup>
>
> Jerusalem, Jerusalem, you who **kill the prophets** and stone those sent to you.
>
> <sup>— [Luke 13:34](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+13:34)</sup>

A comprehensive list of their names is not mentioned in either scripture.

Answer (score -1):

Which prophet was killed?
The history of the children of Israel is full of crime and murder, and they were brave and did not dare to kill the prophets of God, including rioting at the beginning of one day to protect their illegitimate interests, and the 43 prophets of Israel, all of whom were the law of Moses. They told people to kill. In verses 21 and 22 of Surah Al-Imran, God mentions ruthless killing.

Ref:https://www.mashreghnews.ir/news/710645/

Comment: What are you trying to say? the Qur'an clearly says that they did kill the Prophet (Peace be upon them all) of Allah (SWT).